# nmcli not able to use secret service unless nm-applet is running in the background

Tags: networkmanager, nmcli

I have `pass` and `pass_secret_service` configured so that my Wifi passwords are stored in that secret service (org.freedesktop.Secret.Service). So, when I connect to a Wifi network, network manager is supposed to ask the password from the secret service.

However, when I try to connect to a network with `nmcli`, it doesn't work:

```
$ nmcli connection up Foobar
Passwords or encryption keys are required to access the wireless network 'Foobar'.
Warning: password for '802-11-wireless-security.psk' not given in 'passwd-file' and nmcli cannot ask without '--ask' option.
Error: Connection activation failed: Secrets were required, but not provided
```

But if I run `nm-applet` in the background, then it works:

```
$ nm-applet &

$ nmcli connection up Foobar
Passwords or encryption keys are required to access the wireless network 'Foobar'.
Warning: password for '802-11-wireless-security.psk' not given in 'passwd-file' and nmcli cannot ask without '--ask' option.
Connection successfully activated (D-Bus active path: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/15)
```

Why doesn't it work without `nm-applet` running in the background? Any ideas how to fix this?